# Single row CollectionView with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I would like to have a single row collection view at the bottom of the screen with a text field on top of it. Red rectangle is the text field and the green one is the collection view. [image]

This is my setup code:

```
    view.addSubview(queryTextField)
    view.addSubview(suggestionsCollectionView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        queryTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        queryTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        queryTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: suggestionsCollectionView.topAnchor),
        
        suggestionsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        suggestionsCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        suggestionsCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        suggestionsCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160)
    ])
...
private func createCollectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (_, _) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        // item
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)
            )
        )
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 8)
        
        // group
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: .absolute(140)
            ),
            repeatingSubitem: item,
            count: 3
        )
        group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 0, bottom: 16, trailing: 0)
        
        // section
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)
        
        // return
        return section
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve this layout without setting a height constraint on the collection view. I am already specifying the group height `heightDimension: .absolute(140)` so I expect the collection view to be able to calculate it on its own. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A `UICollectionView` lays out its cells ***based on the collection view's frame size*** (and other properties)... if you don't give it a Height, it will say *"no cells will fit"* and you won't get anything.

Comment: So, where would I need to provide the height and how do I calculate it? Do I just take the fixed height I'm providing and add all the insets?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Your code is saying: *"this group should have a height of 140 points"* ... so, if your collection view frame Height is 500-points, the group will use only 140-points. If your collection view frame Height is 200-points, the group will *still* use only 140-points. As a side note, it's not clear why you're using Compositional layout instead of Flow layout -- (the same design issue would apply .. you would still need to set the collection view's Height).

Comment: So where do I provide the height to the collection view?

Comment: In the code you posted, you have: 1suggestionsCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160)` ... isn't that giving you what you want?